# 10 children divide into 2 teams each. How many divisions possible?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

In order to play a game of basketball, $10$ children at a playground divide themselves into

1. $2$ teams of $5$ each
2. $2$ teams of $x_1$ and $x_2$

How many different divisions are possible? This is not a homework problem.

In general, I was thinking of something along the lines of 
$$\binom{10}{x_1\ x_2} + \binom{10}{x_2\ x_1}$$

But as this problem is worded, it's not clear to me if this is overcounting because we have $2$ indistinguishable teams.

---

Textbook says

[image]

Comment: I read on for three more sentences after "10 children divide into two teams each" before doing a double-take! One of those strange sentences that make perfect sense until you realise that they don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(1)** Here, we have $\displaystyle \binom{9}{4} = \dfrac{9!}{4!5!}$. The point that matters here is that it is only after one child we'll call "A" takes a stance as a self-appointed captain to pick the  rest of his/her team that the groups become distinguishable: A's group, and A's rejects. So Captain "A", has in fact, nine-choose $4$ ways to select the other four children on his/her now-identifiable group: the "A-team". The five unpicked (A-rejected) children become, by default, A-team's competition.

**(2)** We can use either the binomial coefficient or its equivalent expression as a multinomial coefficient:  $\displaystyle \binom{10}{x_1} = \binom{10}{x_1, x_2} = \dfrac{10!}{x_1!\cdot x_2 !}$, because $x_1 + x_2 = 10$.

Comment: @Trevor You need to divide the first case by $2!$ because teams aren't important

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: It is not so much that the teams are not important (I guess they are to those kids, at least for the duration of the match). It is that whether designating some subset of $5$ kids as one team (and the rest as the other team) or designating the _complementary_ subset of $5$ kids as one team and the rest as another creates exactly the same partition into the same two teams. In other words this is a partitioning, not a colouring problem.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. Those darn typos!! Does this make sense to you?

Comment: (1) does, but I don't see why we suddenly don't need to divide by $2!$ for (2). The teams are still unlabeled. My *guess* is that it has something to do with the teams becoming distinguishable once they have unequal sizes.

Comment: @Trevor See if my answer makes sense to you

Comment: Yes, @Trevor, exactly: the teams become distinguishable when they are of unequal size. Captain "A" would have two choices: to be on a team with $x_1$ members, or with $x_2$ members, when $x_1\neq x_2$. So the factor of 2 (2 choices) cancels out division by two.

Answer (score 5):

One answer to the $5$-$5$ problem can be written as $\frac{1}{2}\binom{10}{5}$. This can be done by deliberate double-counting, and dividing by $2$ to compensate.

Another way depends on a fact you did not know: Alicia is one of the $10$ people, and she likes to run things.

There are $\dbinom{9}{4}$ ways for Alicia to choose the people who will be on her team. Thus the number of divisions into two teams of $5$ is $\dbinom{9}{4}$.

It is easy to verify that the two answers are numerically the same.

---

For "unbalanced" teams of sizes $x_1,x_2$ where $x_1\ne x_2$, the situation is simpler. There are $\dbinom{10}{x_1}$ ways to choose who will be on the team with $x_1$ people, and now we are done.

Only $5$-$5$ requires special consideration.

Comment: John says Hi to Alicia

Comment: John worked too hard in the unbalanced team situation. I guess he likes to run things even more than Alicia.

Comment: True, I figured it would emphasis more why we use John in the first case if I use it in the second as well.

Comment: My version of the symmetry argument involves adults, not children. There are $\binom{10}{5}$ ways to divide people into two teams of $5$, to wear red and blue. But in a camp for nudists $\dots$.

Comment: That is why! Never been to one of those

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you need to divide by $2!$ because the teams aren't labelled as $A$ or $B$. Another way to see this. Let's say there is a John in the group. We pick John's teammates, choosing 
$9\choose 4$=126. This also determines the other team.

For $(2)$, with $x_1\neq x_2$,  John will either be a member of a team with $x_1$ members or a team with $x_2$ members. We then pick its team remaining member
$$
{9\choose x_1-1}+{9\choose x_2-1}.
$$
Note that in 
$$
{9\choose x_1-1}+{9\choose x_2-1}={10\choose x_1}.
$$
To see this, note that ${n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$, so
$$
\begin{align}
{9\choose x_2-1}&={9\choose 9-(x_2-1)}\\
&={9\choose 10-x_2}\\
&={9\choose x_1}
\end{align}
$$
 Then apply Pascal's rule rule
$$
{n\choose k}={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}
$$
to show

$$
\begin{align}
{10\choose x_1}={10-1\choose x_1-1}+{10-1\choose x_1}= {9\choose x_1-1}+{9\choose x_1} = {9\choose x_1-1}+{9\choose x_2-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It all makes sense to me except for the last equation. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom%289%2Cx_1+-+1%29+%2B+binom%289%2C+%2810-+x_1%29+-+1%29) is what I arrived at with wolframalpha.

Comment: @Trevor See now